# iPhone - copying a UIBezierPath to a CGPath and rendering as the original

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, uibezierpath

I have created a complex UIBezierPath that is composed of several path segments, solid, dashed, lines, colors, arcs, etc. So I have this and now I want to render it to a CGContext.

So, I convert it to a CGPathReference using

```
CGPathRef cgPath = CGPathCreateCopy(aBezierPath.CGPath);
```

The problem is this: in theory, if I want to draw a path on a CGContext, I have to define the stroke width, color, line style, blending mode, etc. for each segment that needs to be different, but the UIBezierPath I have already created contains all this information.

So, I wonder if there is a way to just to "stamp" the CGPath as it is on the CGContext, so it will be stamped with all the original information?

thanks.

Comment: Can you not just use the UIBezierPath's stroke method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DR, you're right: it is very confusing!

But I think Tom is correct, just use [aBezierPath stroke].

So, it would be something like this:

**REF** is a (CGContextRef) which you have built.

**YOURBEZIERPATH** is a (UIBezierPath*).

Inevitably you have to deal with the "drawing upside down" issue, so:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(REF);
CGContextSaveGState(REF);
CGContextTranslateCTM(REF, 0, the height*);
CGContextScaleCTM(REF, 1.0, -1.0);
[YOURBEZIERPATH stroke];
CGContextRestoreGState(REF);
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

So that's it.

Re **your comment below**: *I have an array of UIBezierPaths. Each bezier has its own style and color.*

Does this help? ... Replace the one "stroke" call, with a for loop:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(REF);
CGContextSaveGState(REF);
CGContextTranslateCTM(REF, 0, the height*);
CGContextScaleCTM(REF, 1.0, -1.0);

for each of YOURBEZIERPATH in your array...
    {
    CGContextSaveGState(REF);
    [YOURBEZIERPATH stroke];
    CGContextRestoreGState(REF);
    }

CGContextRestoreGState(REF);
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

You actually do not need to bother using aBezierPath.CGPath, or, a copy thereof.

Again you are right, it is very confusing, the two worlds of UI and CG !!

---

**the height: often something like self.frame.size.height.  I just include this for anyone looking for general example code in the future.*

Comment: Thanks, this almost works for me. My only problem is this: I have an array of UIBezierPaths that I have to draw to the context. Each bezier has its own style and color. When I use your method to stroke the paths in a loop, every time your method is called, all paths, including those previously stroked, changed to the last specified style. For example: I have 3 paths: dashed/blue, solid/red, solid/green. After the first run I have a dashed/blue path. After the second run, I have two solid/red paths and after the third run, all paths change to solid/green.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I was mistaken a few concepts but now it is working like magic. Thanks!!!

Comment: No, I did the inverse, I draw all the paths every time I need to update something. Drawing all the paths is not as slow as I thought, then it is working very well.